# can't compile - Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() not found

Tags: asynchronous, system.net

I have the following code:

```
   public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    DBRepository _repository = new DBRepository();


    public Task<IEnumerable<FileDesc>> Post()
    {
        string folderName = "UploadedFiles";
        string PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + folderName);
        PATH = @"c:\www\qqq";
        string rootUrl = Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri.Replace(Request.RequestUri.AbsolutePath, String.Empty);


        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new CustomMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(PATH);

            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IEnumerable<FileDesc>>(t =>
            {

                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }


                return fileInfo;
            });

            return task;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }

    }
}
```

but I got errors:

> Error 16  'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition
>   for 'IsMimeMultipartContent' and no extension method
>   'IsMimeMultipartContent' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 17  'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' does not contain a definition
>   for 'ReadAsMultipartAsync' and no extension method
>   'ReadAsMultipartAsync' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpContent' could be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Error 18  'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a
>   definition for 'CreateResponse' and no extension method
>   'CreateResponse' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)

why?
I added to project an assembly System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll and have

```
using System.Net.Http.Formatting;
```

on page http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh834190(v=vs.108).aspx carefully said, that this ext. method is in System.Net.Http.Formatting (in System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll)
I tried to compile project under 4.0 and 4.5 - no effect.

PS. I have a solution with the same code, which works perfectly. What can I do?

Comment: The MSDN page you link to shows it in the `System.Net.Http` namespace. Are you missing a using statement?

Comment: thank you! Really stupid error, I checked it twice, but lost in anycase...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the following reference:

"using System.Net.Http;"

{}'s

Comment: I have the same issue but I added this reference and have this line on top. But everything about "multipart" cannot be found. Is there anything else I missed?

Comment: try to enter 'update-package' command @ Package Manager Console